# How to create bulk empty files with incremental filenames in cmd/powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

If I want to create 10 empty `.txt` files with the name pattern `abcd01.txt`, `abcd02.txt`,... ,`abcd10.txt`. How can this be achieved in CMD/PowerShell?

This I what I did to achieve:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt 11; $i++){ New-Item -Path "C:\Users\FOO\Desktop\FOOBAR\abcd",$i,".txt" -ItemType File }
```

This created the files without any file extension. `0`, `1`, `2`,... , `10`.

Then I renamed all files with:

```
 Dir -filter * | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("abcd{0}.cpp" -f $nr++)}
```

Is there a one-line command to make `'n'` empty file with certain `'.xyz'` extension?

Comment: Just `New-Item -Path "abcd$i.txt"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can format leading zeros in a variable which you use in `new-item`:

```
for($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i++){
    $path = "C:\temp\test{0:00}.txt" -f $i
    New-Item -Path $path
}
```

And by the way, your `new-item` did not add any extensions because

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Users\FOO\Desktop\FOOBAR\abcd",$i,".txt"
```

should be

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Users\FOO\Desktop\FOOBAR\abcd$i.txt"
```

---

Also if you need to make `'n'` copies of a file named `'xyz.txt'`, you can use the following:

```
for($i=1; $i -lt 11; $i++){
    $path = "C:\temp\foo\test{0:00}.txt" -f $i
    New-Item $path
    $cont = Get-Content "foo.txt"
    Set-Content $path $cont
}
```

Answer (score 2):

---

[image]

---

> - For the record! With **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** you can do this by:
>
>   ---

In command line:

---

```bat
for /l %N in (1 1 10)do @set "%N=0%N" && cmd /v /c "cd.>"c:\temp\test!%N:~-2!.txt""

:: or ::

for /l %N in (1 1 10)do @set "%N=0%N"&&cmd/v/c"cd.>"c:\temp\test!%N:~-2!.txt""
```

---

**In cmd/bat file:**

---

```bat
for /l %%N in (1 1 10)do set "%%N=0%%N" && cmd /v /c "cd.>"c:\temp\test!%%N:~-2!.txt""

:: or ::

for /l %%N in (1 1 10)do set "%%N=0%%N"&&cmd/v/c"cd.>"c:\temp\test!%%N:~-2!.txt""
```